# How should I write an email asking about the status of my PhD application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette

I applied for a PhD position. As part of the admission process, the professor requested two letters of recommendation, which have been sent. I was then asked to wait a week, but now two weeks have passed and I have not heard from the professor yet. So, I would like to ask about the status of my PhD application. I have no clue how to write it. Please help!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. It would help if you expanded your question with additional details, as it is, it is very vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The question is edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for editing, this is much clearer now and I retracted my previous comment.

Comment: You applied directly to a professor? This is most unusual, normally you apply to a department or a university.

Comment: @RoboKaren: This may be most unusual in some countries, but it isn’t in mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't make too much fuss about it. A simple short and polite email which states that the current state of affairs (letters were sent, you were asked to wait for a week) and inquires whether there were some problems with your application and what its status is.

On the side note, a week waiting is not at all alarming in academia, unless some explicit deadlines are in place. I would wait for at least another 10 days before contacting the professor.

I also agree with RoboKaren, it is highly unusual to apply to a professor. Therefore, another cultural/professional practices may apply in your case. However, a polite email is almost always acceptable (whether or not it is ignored is another question...).

Comment: It really depends on OP's location. In Europe it would not be "highly unusual" to apply directly to a professor, it is actually pretty normal.

Comment: I'm from Europe and the only instances where I heard of such practice is when you transition from undergraduate to graduate within the same institution. In those cases the process is usually somewhat informal, although the future graduate student still has to go through the admission process. "Outsiders" first pass the admission and afterwards go to a professor for supervision. Prior communication with the desired mentor is not unusual, and the professor can convey their impression of you to the committee, but you still need to address your documents to the official admissions.